# How to send POST data with AJAX? And how to get POST data in Web API?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

On my MVC project I have to send a HTML table as an email to the client.

I have an Email Function on a Web API that I should call:

```
public class FunctionsController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("{controller}/email")]
    public void SendEmail(string to, string from, string body, string subject, string bcc)
    {
        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
        smtpClient.Host = "xxxx";
        MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();

        mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mailMessage.Body = body;
        mailMessage.Subject = subject;
        mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(from);
        mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(to));
        mailMessage.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress(bcc));

        smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
    }
```

I'm not sure how to do it.

This is my sendEmail javascript function on my MVC project (using Knockout):

```
   self.sendEmail = function (to, from, body, subject, bcc) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "../API/functions/email",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            'to': to,
            'from': from,
            'body': body,
            'subject': subject,
            'bcc' : bcc
        },
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (data) {
           console.log(ko.toJSON(data));
        }
    });
}
```

How should I get the POST data in the Web API?
Is my javascript function correct?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's always better practice to make a model/viewmodel.

```
public class EmailViewModel
{
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string From { get; set; }
    public string To { get; set; }
    public string Bcc { get; set; }
}
```

Now the controller method will be like:

```
 public void SendEmail(EmailViewModel email)
  {
       .......
  }
```

and the ajax call will be like:

```
 var email={
        'Body': body,
        'Subject': subject ,
        'From': from,
        'To': to,
        'Bcc': ''
   };
   $.ajax({
    url: "../xxx/functions/email/",
    type: "POST",
    data: email,
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (data) {
        callback(data);
    }
});
```

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I updated it in order for it to work. Thanks a million!!

Comment: I can't edit your question, so maybe you should make the folowing changes in your code in order to get it to work:1) you should set the EmailViewModel class to be Public, otherwise it will erroring. 2) You should add JSON.stringify(data) to your data field in the AJAX call. With those changes I got your code to work. Thank You!

Comment: no one can edit others answer. As far i know `JSON.stringify()` is not needed. It can automatically map the model. I have updated the answer. Thnx for your comments.

Answer (score 4):

Your data fields in js:

```
    data: {
        'from_email': from,
        'to': to,
        'autotext': 'true',
        'subject': subject,
        'html': body
    },
```

Should match your controllers parameters names:

```
public void SendEmail(string sBody, string sSubject, string sFrom, string sTo, string sBcc)
```

If the are match MVC will automatically bind them.

So if you want to get your data in controller you should either change your js of controller signature.

For example let's change controller:

```
public void SendEmail(string html, string subject, string from_email, string to, string sBcc)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I edited my question as you suggested, but it is still not working. I'm getting a 404 error: "No action was found on the controller 'Functions' that matches the request." Any suggestion?

Comment: Yeap, API function knows. Your second problem in `url` param. I suppose it should be `url: "/functions/email/",` but i'm not sure here.

Comment: Wow that's amazing! But it still not working, I don't think it's an issue with the url param, on the error you can see that it reaches the API, but can't find an appropriate function to this call. Any idea?

Comment: @Marie what i recommend you to try: change your url to "../SharedAPI/functions/SendEmail" and delete controller attribute `[Route("{controller}/Email")]` i hope your `SendEmail` method in `functions` controller?

Comment: I tried that, didn't help. what really is weired that when I delete the parameters from the signature of the functions on the API, I don't get any error, so I think that something is wrong with the function's parameters or with the js sent parameters..

Comment: Modify the url parameter value to url: "../api/functions/SendEmail/".

Comment: @Marie your param names can be reserved words (like `from`) try to change it somehow to not use reserved words.

Comment: I tried changing to other names but it didn't help, maybe should I add [FromBody] before each parameter?

Comment: @Marie you always can do it. But it's not a good practice. Something wrong with your routes i gess. But i can't see what.

Comment: It's not working either, but could you explain why isn't that a good practice?

Comment: Becouse MVC strong side is binding and when you write FromBody you basically get your values from `HttpContext.Current.Request.Form[key]` You always can do it without this attribute.

Comment: I undertdand. I really want to get it to work as you suggested, I hardcoded the email credentials on the sendEmail function, and tested it without sending parameters and I got the email! It must be something wrong with the parameters!!?!

Comment: @teo van kot, I found out that you MUST send an object on a POST request, you can't do it with single parameters, I changed it to be an object, as Mahbubur Rahman suggested and with some little fixes, it works perfectly! Please check the folowing link: http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Sep/11/Passing-multiple-simple-POST-Values-to-ASPNET-Web-API. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: @Marie don't know that thing. glad to know